# URL redirects properly to all URL protocols except https://www

Tags: tls, url

I have a domain that properly redirects as expected to protocol https://newhavendisplay.com, except for https://www.newhavendisplay.com, which triggers the "This connection is not private" security warning upon visiting. However, if I choose to click the "Proceed to the website anyway", it successfully and securely redirects to https://newhavendisplay.com for all subsequent visits until I clear my browsing history and reopen safari.

see full list of redirects below:

```
newhavendisplay.com             redirects to https://newhavendisplay.com 
www.newhavendisplay.com         redirects to https://newhavendisplay.com
http://newhavendisplay.com      redirects to https://newhavendisplay.com
http://www.newhavendisplay.com  redirects to https://newhavendisplay.com
https://newhavendisplay.com     redirects to https://newhavendisplay.com
https://www.newhavendisplay.com shows "This connection is not private"
```

If I click to view the cert while in the security warning screen I see a total different domain as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please tell us *actual* domain names, and don't redact anything. The error message says that the name doesn't match. When you redact, we don't get the full picture.

Comment: I have updated it the domain name in the original question, thanks. @vidarlo

Comment: Thanks :) In short: the certificate doesn't contain `www.newhavendisplay.com` in the CN or Subject Alternate Name. If noone else answers this, I'll write up an answer tomorrow :)

Comment: In addition to what @vidarlo wrote - the web server for www.newhavendisplay.com is serving an incorrect certificate for www.newhavendisplay.com.  The cert that it is serving is for *.ssl.hwcdn.com.  You can see this if you run `openssl s_client -connect www.newhavendisplay.com:443`.  This is what is causing the browser warning.  www.newhavendisplay.com is a cname for newhavendisplay.com, so they both resolve to the same web server.  Hence, this is most likely a web server configuration problem, where the vhost for www.newhavendisplay.com is configured incorrectly.

Comment: @mti2935 Please post that as an answer. It's fully answering the question.

Comment: Thanks @mti2935. I will look into the DNS records.

Comment: @vidarlo, good idea.  DONE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using openssl to view the certificates that are served for requests to newhavendisplay.com and [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com) respectively:

```
openssl s_client -connect newhavendisplay.com:443
```

shows the following valid leaf certificate for requests to newhavendisplay.com:

```
s:CN = newhavendisplay.com
i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
v:NotBefore: Feb 27 20:12:19 2023 GMT; NotAfter: May 28 20:12:18 2023 GMT
```

However, for requests to www.newhavendisplay.com...

```
openssl s_client -connect www.newhavendisplay.com:443
```

shows this leaf certificate, which is for an entirely different domain:

```
s:CN = *.ssl.hwcdn.net
i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
v:NotBefore: Dec 30 00:00:00 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Jan 19 23:59:59 2024 GMT
```

So, this is what is causing the browser warnings that you are seeing when you make a request to [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com), and hence the reason that redirects from [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com) are not working.

The next step to troubleshooting this would be to see if both newhavendisplay.com and [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com) resolve to the same web server or different web servers.

```
nslookup www.newhavendisplay.com
```

shows:

```
www.newhavendisplay.com canonical name = newhavendisplay.com.
Name:   newhavendisplay.com
Address: 151.139.128.11
```

So, [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com) is a CNAME for newhavendisplay.com, meaning that they both resolve to the same IP address (151.139.128.11).  In other words, the web server at 151.139.128.11 handles requests for both newhavendisplay.com and [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com).

So, this can be only one thing - an incorrect web server configuration.  Most likely the vhost (virtual host) configuration for [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com) is misconfigured, such that it is serving an incorrect certificate for [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com) (i.e. the one above for *.ssl.hwcdn.net).

As [vidario](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/153494/vidarlo) pointed out in the comments above, you might want to get a cert with both newhavendisplay.com and [www.newhavendisplay.com](http://www.newhavendisplay.com) as SAN's, and configure your web server to serve this same cert for both FQDNs.